# Как выводить ошибку во время валидации, одновременно с вводом данных. Без перезагрузки страницы. JS

Tags: javascript, валидация

Есть обычная форма на js, и валидатор на js. При нажатии на submit, он выводит сообщение там, где есть ошибка в валидации. Хотелось бы, чтобы ошибка выводилась без нажатия на submit. Какая тут технология должна использоваться? Я прост не очень разбираюсь в этом. Знаю, что есть несколько готовых библиотек, однако хотелось бы самому.

Comment: _"Есть обычная форма на js, и валидатор на js."_ Серьёзно есть? Не поверим, пока не покажете.

Comment: Здесь отвечают, чтобы помогать. Ваш комментарий тут пользы не несёт, и информативности не несёт. Вопроса может не поняли?? Какую технологию тут использовать?

Comment: Зря вы сразу грубите. В первом комментарии была довольно добродушно сформулированная просьба показать ваш код, чтобы легче было вам помочь.

Comment: Тут использовать технологию задавания вопроса с указанием технических деталей, необходимых для ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UModeL вам в общем-то по делу написал, приложили бы код - вам помогли бы с решение скорее всего.

А по теме, пишете функцию проверяющую инпуты и генерирующую ошибку и вставляете ее вызов не на событие SUBMIT, а на событие INPUT по любому из полей формы.

В таком случае вы получите проверку на ошибки при вводе каждого символа в форму.